# cross-browser way to display listview populated using REST API

Tags: user-interface, web

I have a REST API which provides some information about my resources (let's just say Name, Age, Date of Birth and Country).

I'm looking for a web-based way to see a listview of that data.  As a bonus I'd like to also be able to see the listview on smart phones in addition to desktop web browsers.

I'm looking for the simplest technology to implement this.